# Connection to a local embedded H2 database

Tags: database, google-apps-script, connection, h2, spreadsheet

I have a local H2 database stored on my laptop: `C:\Users\patri\Documents\Collectionneur de recettes v2` in Google Apps Spreadsheet: 
I have duplicated a code I found:

```
var address = 'h2:file:C:\Users\patri\Documents\Collectionneur de recettes v2';
var user = 'SA';
var userPwd = '';
var db = '\recipes';
var dbUrl = 'jdbc:'+ address + ';databaseName=' + db;


function readData() {
 var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
 var stmt = conn.createStatement();
 var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM FOLDERS');
 var metaData=results.getMetaData();
 var numCols = metaData.getColumnCount();

 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 //you can use the following line to get the active sheet
 //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 sheet.clearContents();
 var arr=[];
 for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
  arr.push(metaData.getColumnName(col + 1));
 }
 sheet.appendRow(arr);
 while (results.next()) {
  arr=[];
  for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
   arr.push(results.getString(col + 1));
  }
```

When I execute the code I receive an error message:

> The connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol.

What can I do?

Comment: I've never used H2, so I don't know the specifics, but I would suggest that you search for "h2 server localhost" and then use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs#getting-started-expose) to make it accessible via the web. This should be for dev purposes only though, not for production or persistent use.

Answer (score 1):

Google apps runs on a cloud based server. It doesn't run on your local machine, therefore, unless your local database is made public on a publicly available IP address there is no way for a Google scrip to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

> The connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol.

It is telling you that the subprotocol ***h2*** is not supported by the [Class Jdbc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc).

For knowing what subprotocols Apps Script can handle you can check [External Databases via JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc).